# Plugin link missing in navigation section since 4.5

Tags: sonarqube

I'm about to write a sonar plugin and I'm nearly finished. But after the update to sonarqube 4.5, the navigation section link is missing. I see the plugin to get started in the log and the configuration params are also available. Just the link is missing.

I use the following code:

```
@NavigationSection({NavigationSection.RESOURCE})
public class SoftViz3dPage extends AbstractRubyTemplate implements RubyRailsPage {
...
```

Did something change regarding the extention of the web interface. I was not able to find something.

If you like to take a further look on the code, here it is:
https://github.com/stefanrinderle/sonar-softviz3d

The example code was taken from SoftViz3dPage.java.

Thanks for your hints and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression that is fixed in upcoming 4.5.1 version. See [SONAR-5699](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5699)